# Where are pacman package databases downloaded from?

Tags: database, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

When updating your system on archlinux with `pacman -Suy`, pacman gets *package databases* from somewhere and then downloads packages from mirrors according to versions specified in these databases.

I know these databases are in `/var/lib/pacman/sync/`. My question is, where does pacman get them from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The db files also come from the package [mirrors](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mirrors) specified in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`.

For example in [this core repo](https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/archlinux/core/os/x86_64/):

```
...
core.db             136.6 KiB   2022-Mar-05 12:53
core.db.tar.gz      136.6 KiB   2022-Mar-05 12:53
...
```

The wiki also mentions [what to do if you get an error](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/pacman#Failed_retrieving_file_%27core.db%27_from_mirror):

> **Failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror**
>
> If you receive this error message with correct [mirrors](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mirrors), try setting a different [name server](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Resolv.conf).